# How to print the data returning from $.post()?

Tags: jquery, post, printing, callback

I've my `print` button on one page and data to be printed on another page (`print_invoice.php`). How can I print that returned data in $.post()? Thank you!

```
$('#print').on('click', function(){
    var id = $('#id').val();
    $.post("print_invoice.php", { ref: id },function(data){
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use print function.
like below code:

```
$('#print').on('click', function(){
var id = $('#id').val();
  $.post("print_invoice.php", { ref: id },function(data){
    printdoc("Print Title","style.css",data);
  });
});
function printdoc(wintitle,style,content){
  var mywindow = window.open('',wintitle, 'height=600,width=1000');
  mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>'+wintitle+'</title>');
  mywindow.document.write('<link href="'+style+'" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
  mywindow.document.write('</head><body>');
  mywindow.document.write(content);    

  mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
  mywindow.document.close();
  mywindow.print();    
}
```

if data has full design page then

```
function printdoc(wintitle,style,content){
  var mywindow = window.open('',wintitle, 'height=600,width=1000');
  mywindow.document.write(content);    
  mywindow.document.close();
  mywindow.print();    
}
```

Comment: windows is opening but the content is not writing to the  printing window

Comment: can you write response of $.post here. bcoz above code i tested and its working. so just need to check what  your are getting in `data`